# How can I call on a variable within a function, from outside of that function?

Tags: python

I realise this may be marked as a duplicate however no others are specific to my problem. I have variables within various functions which i need to call separately. I get the error `function pos has no 'stn' member`

I have tried using a global var however is a bit of a bodge and isn't the neatest...

```
def pos():
    stn = int((latest))
pos()

with open('current_data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    data['data'].append({
    'lineone': pos.stn,
    }
)
```

I am expecting these variables to be written to a json (i have not included jso n imports and file set up as it is not relevant to the issue)...however i just get this error `Function 'pos' has no 'stn' member; maybe 'stn_other'?` where `stn_other` is another variable from the `pos` function. I would appreciate the help.

Comment: you need to use `return` to get value from function. Check some basic tutorial on functions

Comment: Excuse me. So add <return stn> to pos() and write: 'lineone': pos()

Comment: @Heyran.rs exactly. However then check tutorial on how to work with json in python. there is json module, part of standard library. what you have so far to write the json file will not work. Also where `latest` comes from? Why it is not parameter to pos()?

Comment: It should define in function or pass it as input. for example: def pos(latest). What numbers do you want to write in your file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is generally bad practice, you need to make `stn` an *attribute* of the function object `pos`:

```
def pos():
    pos.stn = int((latest))
```

Otherwise when `pos` returns, `stn` would go out of scope and be marked for garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks mate, out of interest why is this considered bad practice?

Comment: @EcSync because the "best" or "correct" solution is to just return the things you need from a function - in "good code" the insides of the function could be replaced by a functionally identical "black box" (e.g. variable names are totally changed but the return value is the same for any given input) that you don't need to know the inner workings of to use

Answer (score 1):

If you assign a value to a local variable inside a function, it disappears when the function returns. But you want it to persist. So it seems to me that you want `pos` to be an instance of a class, not a function. When you do `pos.stn` that is certainly what it looks like.

```
class Pos:
    def __init__(self, latest='0'):
        self.stn = int(latest)
```

Then when you make an instance of the class, like this

```
>>> pos = Pos()
```

the data persists inside `pos`:

```
>>> print (pos.stn)
0
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to `return` the result you want to from `pos()` function. Not that I would recommend writing a function for conversion to int - it just adds overhead to available built-in function:

```
import json 

latest = '10'

def pos(latest):
    stn = int(latest)
    return stn

json_data = {'data':[]} # this is something you have in advance
json_data['data'].append(pos(latest))  

with open('current_data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(json_data, outfile, indent=4)
```

resulting current_data.json

```
{
    "data": [
        10
    ]
}
```